# How to extract aic from glm?

Tags: r, glm

How to extract the aic from glm?
I have following code

```
mod <- glm(RESPONSE~..., data=training, family=binomial(link="logit"))
    summary(mod)
glm$aic
```

Output:

> glmfit$aic
>       Error: object 'glmfit' not found
>   glm.fit$aic
>       Error in glm.fit$aic : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
>   glm$aic
>       Error in glm$aic : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
>   aic(glm)
>       Error: could not find function "aic"

Comment: Google? "R extract aic glm"

Comment: `AIC(glm(vs ~ mpg, binomial, mtcars))`

Comment: If your glm object is named `mod`, `glm$aic` won't succeed but `mod$aic` will

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on the correct comment from @rawr. `AIC()` is a function that takes a model object as an argument. In your code example you create a model object `mod`, this needs to be passed to the `AIC()` function.

```
mod <- glm(RESPONSE~..., data=training, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(mod)
AIC(mod)
```

Comment: The documentation for this function refers to aic not AIC. Thank you for your response.